# websocket server/client only works on LAN

Tags: javascript, python, websocket

I'm trying to make a chat server with a web client and python backend. Everything works fine on the local network (both localhost and different computers under the same router). However, when I try to connect with my external IP it doesn't work. (this is true for both a JavaScript and Python client). The external port is forwarded on TCP.

Backend server content is the basic server shown on the documentation for the Python websockets library.
Client is a JS oneliner that is only trying to connect: `var client = new WebSocket("ws://ip:port");`

EDIT: I'm actually stupid. I thought you could access the external IP on the local network and it would have the same effect. I believed this because ssh works that way.

Comment: Have you verified that you can access your public ip from another network?

Comment: if your server is at home then you will need to configure port forwarding in your router. routers don't allow unsolicited incoming traffic.

Comment: @Joel Things like ssh and minecraft servers work, so yes.

Comment: And you have opened the port for the websocket address? Then its just a matter of entering the ip:port. If that doesn't work you have to take another look at your port-forwarding

Comment: @Joel I had made the assumption that you could access the external IP from the internal network. SSH works this way, but apparently websockets doesn't. Thank you for your help though, it gave me the idea to test it.

Comment: @JohnJorgensen Hmm, don't think that should be an issue. Must've been something else I believe. Anyway, good thing you solved it.